# Styled search bar completely disappears in IE7

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I styled a search bar on this site [here](http://eezzyweb.com/)

It disappears completely in IE7 (I do not need to support IE6).
It works fine in any other browser I tested it so far (Chrome, IE8, Safari, Firefox, Opera).

I tried to remove and re-add CSS properties without success

HTML

```
<div id="access-search">
   <form id="searchform" method="get" action="http://eezzyweb.com">
      <div>
         <input id="s" name="s" type="text" value="" size="20" tabindex="1" />
         <label for="s">
            <input id="searchsubmit" name="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="Search" tabindex="2" />
         </label>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#searchform div{
position:relative;
float:right;
display:inline;
top:6px;
right:10px;
width:250px;
height:22px;
background:url(images/search-bkg-complete.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
input#s{
position:relative;
width:210px;
height:16px;
margin-left:5px;
background:none;
padding:3px 0;
}
#searchsubmit {
background:url(images/submit-button.png) 0 2px no-repeat;
float:right;
width:22px;
height:21px;
text-indent:-9999px;
text-transform:capitalize;
}
input#s, #searchsubmit{
vertical-align:middle;
border:0;
line-height:1;
font-size:90%;
}
#searchsubmit:hover{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: @AdamWenger done...a bit late....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol...I solved it. There was an overflow:hidden on a parent container!

Comment: In order to mark a question as answered/solved, click the green check mark next to your answer to accept it. This will remove it from the list of unanswered questions.